# json parsing using jq

Tags: json, jq

I am trying to parse a JSON file

input content:

```
{
   "pools":[
      {
         "id":"403add1f-25d9-4a24-99ff-12c5559fecfa",
         "members":[
            {
               "id":"2b8e1155-aae0-4999-a038-ec900fd8e5b6"
            },
            {
               "id":"3010bc81-e76d-462a-b4cc-2dc0888d65d2"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":"ranj-25d9-4a24-99ff-12c5559fecfa",
         "members":[
            {
               "id":"ranj-aae0-4999-a038-ec900fd8e5b6"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "pools_links":[

   ]
}
```

Expected output:

```
403add1f-25d9-4a24-99ff-12c5559fecfa=2
ranj-25d9-4a24-99ff-12c5559fecfa=1
```

the '403add1f-25d9-4a24-99ff-12c5559fecfa' is reading from the id, and the 2 is the number of members.

Does anyone have an idea of how to do it in one jq call?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Easy enough:

```
jq -r '.pools[] | "\(.id)=\(.members|length)"'
```

`-r` turns on raw (non-JSON) output so that we can format the output line directly.